KiCad, how to export gerbers for individual sections of a project?
Because of "reasons" a large PCB has evolved into two PCBs.
Is there a way of exporting gerbers for the two PCBs individually without breaking the project into two?

I have similar problem when panelizing PCB. I must copy final PCB and prepare panel in separate file, i.e. redo it when original PCB is changed,

Do you have the PCBs arranged as say two rectangles, offset by something convenient?

@jonathanjo It is two shapes sitting next to each other. They are not rectangles and there is not specific distance between them.

But can't you just move one of the sub-PCBs so that the two are clearly separated in the layout, to make splitting the Gerber easy and safe? Or do "reasons" force you to preserve the relative arrangement of the two PCBs in the superproject?

What I usually do is delete one of the boards, export gerbers (perhaps after moving things such that the origin is in a better location), and then undo the (move and) delete. Then repeat for each board you need separate gerbers for.
Making multiple boards in a single file, or even multiple PCB files for a single project, is not currently supported by KiCad; if this is a feature you want, I highly encourage you to make a feature request (or upvote/comment on an existing one, if there is one--I think there may be) on the KiCad issue tracker.

I believe the place to look for feature requests, and add new ones is: https://gitlab.com/kicad/code/kicad/-/issues

This is also what I do.

@ChrisKnudsen yes, that is indeed the place. Be aware that all reports on there need to have the version info copied from a current version of KiCad (help->about->copy version info button), or they get automatically closed by the janitor bot. (This is so people don't report bugs on an outdated version, because the KiCad team doesn't have the manpower to keep supporting old versions. It doesn't matter as much for feature requests but the bot doesn't differentiate.)

Most people will edit the PCB then create the Gerbers, carefully not saving the file.  Another method is to put Board A and Board B in the same "PCB" but on different layers.  Then you can output your correct Gerbers by simple layer choices in the Gerber Output.
But a much better method is Board A and Board B in the same "PCB" but offset with some clear dividing line, and then using a simple Gerber post-processor which crops the output.
This has the advantage of not being specific to KiCAD and not involving any potentially error-prone manual edits of your design in the CAD tool; it also means that your manufacturing files of your two boards are made at the identical time from the identical version with the identical settings.
Gerber is a quite simple text format with quite simple semantics and is designed to be post-processed.  It's nowhere near as complex as PostScript, for example, or the .kicad_pcb format.
Practical Example
If you have completely disjoint areas (perhaps Board A has X coordinates left of some value, board B to the right) this is straightforward to do.  Then you check your post-processed Gerbers in the usual way with whatever viewer you like.
Of course, you don't need to make a completely general tool: just one which deals with the subset of Gerber format your CAD files actually contain, which is in the case of KiCAD (and LibrePCB) a very limited subset.
In our case (tested in KiCAD 8.0.3), the lines we want to include or omit all look like this:
X65810000Y-77950000D03

Which means: go to position (65.1, -77.95) mm and make some kind of mark.  It turns out no other line begins with X, and so we can just discriminate of the first character; and also no other lines have absolute coordinates, so we need all the other lines without having to understand them.
It turns out the Excellon drill files have the same format, except they are (recommended) to be with decimal points.
Test
This is the sample two-boards-in-one-PCB, each 50 mm wide, starting at X=50 and X=150.  Made in KiCAD 8. Everything left of say X=120mm is in board A, to the right is board B.

Result
We make the output Gerbers and drill files (settings shown below) and crop them into two directories.  The results look like this:
This is A in the Gerber Viewer:

This is B in the Gerber Viewer:

Settings
These were made with default Gerber settings:


Method
We want to split on say X=120 mm, so the algorithm to apply to each Gerber file is:
for each line
  if line begins with "X" then
    extract the first number after that "X"
    if that number < 120 mm then
      output it
    endif
  else if the line doesn't begin with "X" then
    output it
  endif
endfor

Python Script
A rough-and-ready Python script to do the works is as follows.
Tested in Python 3.10 on Linux, though should work on other platforms.
Expected to be in an executable file in the path.
It blanks the lines which aren't needed, which means it is trivial to compare to the original files (with eg diff -y)
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# gcrop
# simple gerber cropping script
# for kicad 8 output gerber and excellon drill files
# 
#   gcrop left 120000000 thing-F_Cu.gbr   # gerbers in nanometres
#   gcrop right 120000000 thing-F_Cu.gbr
#   gcrop left 12.5 thing-PTH.drl         # excellon in mm or inch     
#   gcrop right 12.5 thing-PTH.drl
#   gcrop above 12.5 thing-PTH.drl        # can test against y     
#   gcrop below 12.5 thing-PTH.drl

import sys
import re

def doom(fmt, *args):
    print(fmt % args, file=sys.stderr)
    exit(1)

def safefloat(s):
    try:
        res = float(s)
    except:
        doom("expected decimal number, found %s", repr(s))
    return res

posnames = ["above", "below", "left", "right"]

def main(argc, argv):
    if argc != 4:
        doom("Usage: %s position cutval filename",
            argv[0])

    pos = argv[1]
    if pos not in posnames:
       doom("Want position in %s, have %s", posnames, repr(pos))
    cutval = safefloat(argv[2])
    filename = argv[3]

    try:
        lines = open(filename, "r").read().splitlines()
    except IOError as e:
        doom("Error converting file %s (%s)",
            filename, e.strerror)

    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("X"):
            m = re.match("X([+-]?[0-9.]+)Y([+-]?[0-9.]+)", line)
            if not m:
                doom("Bad X line %s", repr(line))
            x = safefloat(m.group(1))
            y = safefloat(m.group(2))
            if ((pos == "left") and (x >= cutval)) or \
                    ((pos == "right") and (x < cutval)) or \
                    ((pos == "above") and (y >= cutval)) or \
                    ((pos == "below") and (y < cutval)):
                line = ""
        print(line)

main(len(sys.argv), sys.argv)

We do this for all the Gerber files into a directory A; and then again into a directory B.  Note that the units for the drill file are millimetres not nanometres.
On Bourne shell command line you can do it like this, assumed to be in the directory of the .gbr and .drl files, with gcrop script somewhere in the path such as ~/bin.
mkdir A B
for x in *.gbr; do
    gcrop left 120000000 $x > A/$x
    gcrop right 120000000 $x > B/$x
done
for x in *.drl; do
    gcrop left 120 $x > A/$x
    gcrop right 120 $x > B/$x
done

Caveats
In principle Gerbers can be very complex and cropping can be tricky if for example the crop line crosses a pad or text or whatever.  In practice if you want to simply omit clearly separated boards the trivial mechanism here works perfectly well.

To elaborate, interpreting "step-and-repeat" or various rotations can be very difficult.  But we know from the source code (see below) KiCAD doesn't emit SR commands.
Similarly, there are lots of ways of specifying a flash at a given X position, but we know from the source KiCAD always emits flashes in the simple format described here.

Reference
I'm sure you'll find many libraries to help, but you might consider writing straight from the specification:

Gerber file web site https://www.ucamco.com/en/gerber
Gerber v2 and v3 File Specification PDF

In KiCAD there is a common plotting layer which deals with Gerbers, PDF, etc.  This is where we'd do cropping selection if we were modifying KiCAD.  Then there's a file per output syntax, where we can see exactly what Gerber commands KiCAD can actually output.  (Same mechanism for PDF, DXF, etc.)

KiCAD source is here https://gitlab.com/kicad
Generic plotting: common/plotters/common_plot_functions.cpp
Gerber detail: common/plotters/GERBER_plotter.cpp
Drill files are made by pcbnew/exporters/gendrill_Excellon_writer.cpp or gendrill_gerber_writer.cpp


If there's enough interest in this, I'll happily put the scripts in a public git repository.
